# Associativity of monads

Tags: haskell

```
newtype Set a = Set [a]
```

New Type Set that contains a list.
    empty :: Set a
    empty = Set []

```
sing :: a -> Set a
sing x = Set [x]
```

Function to creat a set.

```
memSet :: (Eq a) => a -> Set a -> Bool
memSet _ (Set []) = False
memSet x (Set xs)
    | elem x xs = True
    | otherwise = False

{-
makeSet :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Set a
makeSet [] = empty
makeset (x:xs) = union (sing x) (makeSet xs)
-- etc
-- we need the obvious stuff:

union        :: Set a -> Set a -> Set a
unionMult    :: [ Set a ] -> Set a
intersection :: Set a -> Set a -> Set a
subSet       :: Set a -> Set a -> Bool
mapSet       :: (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
mapset f (Set xs) = makeSet (map f xs)
-}

-- now making it a monad:
instance Monad Set where
   return = sing
   (Set x) >>= f =  unionMult (map f x)
```

Verification:

Left identity:

```
return a >>= f ≡ f a
```

Right identity:

```
 m >>= return ≡ m
```

Associativity:

```
 (m >>= f) >>= g ≡ m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

left:

```
return x >>= f
(Set [x]) >>= f
unionMult (map f [x])
unionMult [ (f x) ] = f x
```

right:

```
(Set [xs]) >>= return
unionMult (map return [xs])
unionMult [ys]
Set [xs]
```

Need help with the last one.

Comment: We need the implementation of `unionConcat`, since it's a central part of the monad

Comment: I haven't implemented it it is supposed to give a Set a. It is like concat for lists.

Answer (score 2):

unionConcat is already defined in Data.Set....  To be concrete, I will use the following definiitions in this proof

```
unionConcat = Data.Set.unions
return = Data.Set.fromList [a]
```

(I will use other functions defined in Data.Set here, some may require "Ord a", presumably that won't be a problem).

I also make use of the following properties

```
union x y = fromList (toList x ++ toList y)
concat . map (:[]) = id
```

The first states that the union of two sets can be obtained by taking a list of items in the set, concatinating them, then removing the repeats....  This follows from the definition of what a set is

The second property just states that concat and map (:[]) are inverses of each other.  This should also be obvious from the definition of concat

```
map (:[]) [a, b, c, ....] = [[a], [b], [c], ....]
concat [[a], [b], [c], ....] = [a, b, c, ....]
```

(In order to really finish this proof, I would have to show that these properties follow from the Haskell definitions of (:[]), concat and union, but this is more detail that I think you want, and the actual definitions might change from version to version, so we will just have to assume that the writers of these functions followed the spirit of how sets and concat should work).

(In case it isn't obvious, remember the monkey operator (:[]) wraps single elements in brackets- (:[]) x = [x]).

Since "unions" is just a multiple appliction of "union", and "concat" is just a multiple application of (++), the first propterty can be generalized to

```
unions sets = fromList (concat $ map toLists sets)
```

Now for the proof-

```
y >>= return 
= unions $ map return (toList y)
= unions $ map (fromList . (:[])) (toList y)
= unions $ map fromList $ map (:[]) (toList y)
= unions $ map fromList $ map (:[]) $ toList y
= fromList $ concat $ map toList $ map fromList $ map (:[]) (toList y)
= fromList $ concat $ map (:[]) (toList y)
= fromList $ toList y
= y
```

QED

---

Edit- See discussion below, I made a mistake and proved the wrong law (d'oh, I should have just read the title of the question :) ), so I am adding the correct one (associativity) below.

Two prove associativity, we need to use two properties....

```
property 1 - toList (x >>= f) = su (toList x >>=' toList . f)
property 2 - su (x >>=' f) = su (su x >>=' f)
```

where su sorts and uniqs a list, ie-

```
su [4,2,4,1] = [1,2,4],
```

and >>=' is the array bind operator,

```
x >>=' f = concat . map f x
```

The first property should be obvious....  It just states that you can get the result of x >>= f in two different ways, either by applying f to the values in the set x and taking the union, or to the exact same values in the corresponding list, and concating the values.  The only hitch is that you might get repeat values in the list (the set couldn't even allow that), so you apply the su function on the right side to canonicalize the result (note that toList also outputs in the same form).

The second property states that if you sort/uniq a result at the end of a pipeline of binds, you can also perform it earlier in the pipeline without changing the answer.  Again, this should be obvious....  Adding/removing duplicates or reordering the values with the initial list only add/removes duplicates or reorders the final result.  But we are going to remove the duplicates and reorder at the end anyway, so it doesn't matter.

(A more rigorous proof of these two properties could be given based on the definitions of map/concat, toList, etc, but it would blow up the size of this posting....  I'll assume that everyone's intuition is strong enough and continue....)

Using these, I can now show you the proof.  The general plan is to use the known associativity of the array bind operator, and the relationship of arrays with sets to show that the set bind operator must also be associative.

Since

```
toList set1 == toList set2
```

implies that

```
set1 == set2
```

I can prove

```
toList ((y >>= f) >>= g) = toList (y >>= (\x -> f x >>= g))
```

to get the desired result.

```
toList ((y >>= f) >>= g)
su (toList (y >>= f) >>=' toList . g) --by property 1
su (su (toList y >>=' toList . f) >>=' toList . g) --by property 1
su ((toList y >>=' toList . f) >>=' toList . g) --by property 2
su (toList y >>=' (\x -> (toList . f) x >>=' toList . g)) --by the associativity of the array bind operator
su (toList y >>=' (\x -> su (toList (f x) >>=' toList . g))) --by property 2 and associativity of (.)
su (toList y >>=' (\x -> toList (f x >>= g))) --by property 1
su (toList y >>=' toList (\x -> f x >>= g)) --by associativity of (.)
su (su (toList y >>=' toList (\x -> f x >>= g))) --by property 2
su (toList (y >>= (\x -> f x >>= g))) --by property 1
toList (y >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)) --because toList is already sorted/uniqued
```

QED

Comment: Oops, I misread the question twice....  First I proved the wrong identity.  I can fix that, but I also just realized, you aren't using actual data Sets (ie- collections where members can appear 0 or 1 times)....  You defined a new data type called Set which is a wrapper around the usual array.  Did you actually mean for this to be a mathematical set, or really just an array with a new bind and return operator?

Comment: By the way, if your set is actually just a list, and as you mention above, concat is just the same as concat for lists, then the proof is trivial- Everything is isomorphic to the usual array, and all the proofs are direct mappings to the usual proof for arrays....  Somehow I don't think you meant that though (ie - you really did intend to create a Data.Set style set, which doesn't directly correspond to arrays).  If so, let me know and I can finish up what I did above for the correct identity.

Comment: But what is unionMult?  We need this to answer the question.  Two obvious possibilities exist.  Either unionMult concats sets and removes duplicate items, or it leaves them in (in which case this isn't really a set).  If it is the former, I can fix my answer above by adding the correct identity.  If the latter, you have an array, not a set and the solution would be the same as for arrays.  Or is it something else altogether?

Comment: UnionMult takes e.g sets A and B and Creates a Set C .
if A=[1, 2, 3] B= [1,5,6] then C=[1,2,3,5,6]

Answer (score 2):

Since `Set a` is just a `newtype` around `[a]` lets use `[]` directly. The proofs will be similar so long as we use `Set`'s instances; we'll be able to use `[]`'s constructors (somewhat) directly. That's nice because then we can prove things inductively.

We want to show that for all `xs :: [a]` `xs >>= return == xs`. Let's first assume that `xs == []`.

```
[] >>= return
unionConcat (map return [])
unionConcat []
[]
```

Without defining `unionConcat` we can use this to show that unless `unionConcat [] = []` holds, we can't get associativity. We'll keep that in mind for later.

Now we'll do the inductive step, assuming that we have some particular `xs :: [a]` where `xs >>= return == xs`, can we show that `(x:xs) >>= return == x:xs`?

```
(x:xs) >>= return
unionConcat (map return (x:xs))
unionConcat (return x : map return xs)
...
x : unionConcat (map return xs)
x : (xs >>= return)
x:xs                                   -- working upward from the bottom here
```

Providing yet another property of `unionConcat`---

```
unionConcat (return x : xs) = x : unionConcat xs
```

So even before we have a definition of `unionConcat` we can already say that our properties will hold contingent on it following certain properties of its own. We ought to translate the `(:)` constructor back into a notion for sets, though.

```
unionConcat (return x : xs) = insert x (unionConcat xs)
```

Comment: Hi 
i can't see how this proves the last rule. 
Associativity: 
(m >>= f) >>= g ≡ m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)

I have a sol to first to rules but can't solve it for the last one.

Comment: I didn't solve it, but instead just indicated the process you could use to let your proofs provide more information about the right properties of unionConcat. Without a working definition of `Set` and `unionConcat` it'll be hard to prove anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
> U :: [Setx] --> Set x 
> 
> (m >>= f) >>= g ≡  m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
> VL(leftSide)
> (m >>= f) >>= g
> (Set x >>= f) >>=g  <=>
> (U(map f x)) >>=g  <=> (U(map f x)=Set y)
> Set y >>= g           <=>
> 
> 
> HL:(right Side)
> m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)        <=>
> Set x >>=(\x -> f x >>= g) (funktionen \x -> f x gives a Set y it will consume value of  x.)
```

But this prrof i wrong. (U= UnionMult.)
I was told that i should try to create a function conposition for both left side and right side. It will help in showing that right side and left side are equal.
HL: rightSide
VL leftSide
want to show VL==HL